# How to make CSS ::selection background a filter of the background color

Tags: html, css

If I have a colored background and want to make text on that background some color derived from the background color, how could I do that?

I thought something like:

```
::selection {
  backdrop-filter: brightness(.25);
}
```

but alas it does not work. Here we assume the child element doesn't know what color the background is so I can't hardcode it.

Comment: I don't think you can even apply backdrop-filter to ::selection, there is a restriction in the properties you can use there

Comment: Would some mix blend mode setting help? Depends what 'derived from' effect you want though.

Comment: mix-blend-mode seems to not work with ::selection either :/

Answer (score 0):

Only certain CSS properties can be used with `::selection`

```
>     color
>     background-color
>     text-decoration and its associated properties
>     text-shadow
>     stroke-color, fill-color and stroke-width
```

`backdrop-filter` not working in `::selection`,
You can set the background or color same the body background

For example, If the background is white and the text color is black

```
::selection {
  color: #ddd;
}
```